# Icon is not showing up

Tags: html, css, icons

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    
 
    <title>Pokemon Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" class="css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" class="css">
 
</head>
 
<body>
 navigation bar starts here-->
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
   <nav class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pokemon Company</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home
            <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Pokemon</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Catch Pokemon</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Location</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">California</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">London action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mumbai</a>

            <a class="dropdown-header">Upcoming Gigs</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brazil</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">China</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus fa-beat"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>


</nav>
 
</nav>
    </div>
navigation bar ends here-->

 
 
carousel starts here-->
     <div id="abc" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#abc" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#abc" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#abc" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="/images/p1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2>Card Game</h2>
        <p>Pokemon card game begins here choose your pokemon carefully</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/images/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
       <h2>Pikachu</h2>
        <p>A electric type pokemon that uses thunderbolt as its special attack</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/images/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2>Togepi</h2>
        <p>A psycic pokemon that uses teleport when finds itself in danger</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#abc" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#abc" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
carousel ends here-->




    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-qKXV1j0HvMUeCBQ+QVp7JcfGl760yU08IQ+GpUo5hlbpg51QRiuqHAJz8+BrxE/N" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pSPl4ortUMiOzBwaBCKWyLN56qayNCtQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Font Awesome CSS file without `@font-face` rules. Try change it to this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" class="css">
```